# How can I clone a dual-boot with Windows 10 and Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, clone

I have been experimenting with cloning dual boots, with mixed success.

Acronis True Image successfully will clone a Windows 10 installation, but all Linux (Ubuntu base) OS's are broken.

Similarly, when using Clonezilla, and later dd to clone, the Linux partitions boot properly, but Windows throws an error.

Feel free to assume the drives are the same size, but honestly bonus points if it supports cloning to different sized drives.

Thanks!! Been trying to crack this nut for years.

Comment: I will take a SWAG can you clone Windows without the Linux partition so it will boot. Next boot the new drive then use a bootable thumb drive to install linux beside windows, then update it with the timeshift backup you saved from the good linux partition you want to clone? This will take more time but I think it will work. I have read of people using this to duplicate a linux drive nothing said about more than one OS partition.

Comment: Do you have ability to connect both drives to one computer and boot with Ubuntu Live?

Answer (score 1):

Acronis True Image successfully will clone a Windows 10 installation. So that is done.

You can clone your Linux partitions with GParted. Boot a 'Live'-USB and clone the partitions. Resize if needed/wanted.
Your partitions will have other UUID's (to know the UUID use GParted), so you need to adjust the following files:

- fstab (found in /etc)
- In etc/grub.d you need to modify your 10_linux_proxy file and 30_OS_prober (for your Windows OS). Then do a `sudo update-grub`.
- Another UUID to change is the in the EFI-partition (/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg).

Comment: In GParted rightclick on a partition then choose 'information' to find out the UUID.